# MongoDB coleções

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, json, node.js, mongodb

Tenho um banco de dados em mongo com a seguintes coleções "ProdutosServiços" e "estoque" onde a coleção estoque ira informar o valor de estoque de um registro dentro da coleção produtos e serviço mas ao olhar dentro da coleção estoque como consigo identificar qual registro ali faz referencia ao produto dentro da coleção ProdutoServiço ??

Coleção produto e serviço

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e000684de9b5c1ca04700ee"), 
"_t" : [
    "ProdutoServico", 
    "Produto"
], 
"InformacoesPesquisa" : [
    "produto", 
    "teste", 
    "manutencao", 
    "9999"
], 
"Versao" : "737419.16:21:07.5563807", 
"Ativo" : true, 
"CodigoInterno" : "9999", 
"Descricao" : "produto teste manutenção", 
"IndicadorArredondamentoTruncamento" : {
    "_t" : "Truncamento"
}, 
"IndicadorProducaoPropriaTerceiro" : {
    "_t" : "Terceiro"
}, 
"TipoItem" : {
    "Codigo" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Descricao" : "Mercadoria para Revenda"
}, 
"UnidadeMedida" : {
    "_t" : "UnidadeMedida", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfcae7faacd1b2104f7f3cc"), 
    "InformacoesPesquisa" : [
        "unidade", 
        "un"
    ], 
    "Descricao" : "Unidade", 
    "Sigla" : "UN"
}, 
"UnidadeMedidaTributavel" : {
    "_t" : "UnidadeMedida", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfcae7faacd1b2104f7f3cc"), 
    "InformacoesPesquisa" : [
        "unidade", 
        "un"
    ], 
    "Descricao" : "Unidade", 
    "Sigla" : "UN"
}, 
"FatorUnidadeMedidaTributavel" : 0.0, 
"SubGrupoReferencia" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), 
"Hash" : "KVMxFoQglkNZ0IsRmimKfZJrXf2gi+V3ubWVdYoBzVfrR0YxJSXeTg==", 
"Alteracoes" : [

], 
"Vendavel" : true, 
"Imagem" : BinData(0, "H4sIAHEpBl4A/w=="), 
"PesoLiquido" : 0.0, 
"PesoBruto" : 0.0, 
"Pesavel" : true, 
"IntervaloValidade" : {
    "_t" : "Dia", 
    "TempoValidade" : NumberInt(0)
}}
```

coleção estoque

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e08a7d393f1780eec7b326d"), 
"_t" : "Estoque", 
"InformacoesPesquisa" : [

], 
"Quantidades" : [

], 
"QuantidadesReservadas" : [

], 
"QuantidadeCompra" : 0.0, 
"TotalCompra" : 0.0, 
"DataUltimaCompra" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"DataUltimaVenda" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"PrecoUltimaCompra" : 0.0, 
"QuantidadeMaxima" : 0.0, 
"QuantidadeMinima" : 0.0, 
"PermiteVendaFracionada" : true, 
"QuantidadeConsignada" : 0.0, 
"PodeEditarQuantidade" : "24T4GMQVm0ZDoOSO+Kj7Bc6LAEvuFYfb9BBV8MQrZXbrR0YxJSXeTg=="}
```

OBS: são documentos distintos exatamente por não saber qual documento dentro da coleção estoque e referente ao documento da coleção ProdutoServiço